# Create new date for temporal layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, timemanager

I have a bunch of features (e.g. 'sampling point 1') and am storing a bunch of environmental data for each feature (e.g. `'pH'`, `'EC'`, etc.) plus a date. The new time manager for QGIS makes exploring this data great.

However, what I can't figure out is some simple way of inputting new data. Specifically I would like to recreate each feature for each new date so that the attribute table that originally looked something like this:

```
fid | name    | pH  | date
--- | ---     | --- | ---
1   | point 1 | 6   | 1990-01-01
2   | point 2 | 5   | 1990-01-01
3   | point 1 | 7   | 2020-05-01 
4   | point 2 | 7   | 2020-05-01
```

Could be updated to something like this:

```
fid | name    | pH   | date
--- | ---     | ---  | ---
1   | point 1 | 6    | 1990-01-01
2   | point 2 | 5    | 1990-01-01
3   | point 1 | 7    | 2020-05-01 
4   | point 2 | 7    | 2020-05-01
5   | point 1 | NULL | 2020-06-01
6   | point 2 | NULL | 2020-06-01
```

I can filter by the latest date, select the filtered features, copy the selected features, paste as a new temporary layer, change the date and attributes and then copy these features and paste them back into the original layer. But that seems very convoluted.

Is there a simpler way to create a new date for the features in a layer? Or am I just approaching the problem wrong way?

Comment: Am I correctly understand you would like to possess the whole set of attributes once again in the same Attribute table, for which the `"ph"`-value is `NULL`? What do you intend to do with geometry of those feature? Shall they be doubled or what?

Comment: What I want is to record the change in attributes of a set of geographic features over time. As I said, maybe I'm just approaching the problem incorrectly, but it seems to me that the way to do that is to have a set of geometries that get duplicated as new features for every new date. Preferably I would also be able to duplicate the values of some of the attributes (like "name") but not others (like "pH").

Comment: How is your data stored and in which Format?

Comment: At the moment they are gpkg, but I'm still in the setup phase, so changing formats is easy if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another probably a more simpler solution can be achieved with the following workflow

**Step 1.** Select all features in that layer

**Step 2.** Start editing the layer

**Step 3.** Copy and paste selected features in the same layer

**Step 4.** Modify values in `"pH"` field with `''` using the Field Calculator. Do not forget to click `"Update selected"`

**Step 5.** Update the `"id"` for new feature with `maximum("id") + @row_number`  using the Field Calculator. Do not forget to click `"Update selected"`

**Step 6.** Change the date with `to_date('2020-06-' || format_date(to_date("date"), 'dd'))`

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping there would be something a bit more streamlined, because it will be an end user who will be the one who adds new data for each new date.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the Question was interpreted correctly.

In QGIS I can suggest using a *Virtual Layer* through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there is one point layer `"test"` with its corresponding attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to achieve the result, i.e. to duplicate all points in the same layer while modifying some values as well generating new ids.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    -- number series
    WITH RECURSIVE generate_series(category) AS (
        SELECT conf.start
        FROM conf
        UNION ALL
        SELECT category + conf.step
        FROM generate_series, conf
        WHERE category + conf.step <= conf.stop
    ),

    -- configuration
    conf AS (
        SELECT MAX(CAST("id"  AS INTEGER)) + 1 AS start,
               2*COUNT() AS stop,
               1 AS step
        FROM test
    )
    
    -- creating new table with the corresponding order of values
    SELECT t."osm_id",
           NULL AS "lastchange",
           gs.category AS id,
           t."lat",
           t."lon",
           t."Name",
           t.geometry 
    FROM generate_series AS gs, conf AS c
    JOIN test AS t ON t."id" = gs.category - c.stop/2
)

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM test
```

The output Virtual Layer will look like as following.

[image: result]

*where*

- new values where set to `NULL` for the Attribute `"lastchange"`
- added an `"id"`s for new values

*Note* that each location contains double geometries

---

**References:**

- [W3Schools | SQL CAST() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp)